# WASP Chain Setup TCP Connection Refused Error

Tags: iota-network, tangle, node

I am trying to setup a WASP Chain to test deploy a EVM smart contract.
However, I try to *wasp-cli request-funds* or *wasp-cli chain deploy* I am getting a *dial tcp connect:connection refused* error.
[image]

This is what my *wasp-cli.json* looks like.

[image]

How can I resolve this error? Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This error was due to setting up only 1 WASP node but configurign for more than the existing number of nodesin the wasp-cli.json.
Upon removing the "1" and "n" node configurations, chain deployment has been successful.
In addition, the goshimmer api node has been outdated and must be updated to *wasp-cli set goshimmer.api https://api.goshimmer.sc.iota.org*